# How to display my JSON datas expressjs/angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, express

I am a beginner in JSON.

I would like to display all my JSON datas in my html `<div>`, but I am not sure how to do it with an object using EXPRESSJS.

**Find bellow my JSON Datas**

```
app.post("/form",function(req,res)
{
    var departure=req.body.departure;
    var destination=req.body.destination;

        response = {
            "flights": [{
                "departure": departure,
                    "destination": destination,
                    "time": {
                        departure: 10,
                        destination: 12
                    },
                    "price": 2000
            }, {
                "departure": departure,
                    "destination": destination,
                    "time": {
                        departure: 12,
                        destination: 14
                    },
                    "price": 4000
            }, {
                "departure": departure,
                    "destination": destination,
                    "time": {
                        departure: 14,
                        destination: 16
                    },
                    "price": 8000
            }]
        };
    res.json({departure: departure, destination: destination});
});
```

**My html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in response">
    <dir>{{item.departure}}</dir>
    <dir>{{item.destination}}</dir>
    <dir>{{item.time.departure}}</dir>
    <dir>{{item.time.destination}}</dir>
    <dir>{{item.price}}</dir>
</div>
```

**AngularJS code**

```
app.controller('formController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'form';
    $scope.departure = '';
    $scope.destination = '';
    $scope.submit = function() {
        $http.post('/form', {
            departure: $scope.departure,
            destination: $scope.destination
        }).then(function(res) {
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });
    }
});
```

At the moment it is displaying only my departure and destination as I asked. Is there a way to display all my datas by writing my res.json() without doing it variable by variable ? I guess I have to do something with ng-repeat as well ?

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need use ng-repeat

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('myController',function($scope){
    $scope.response = {
            "flights": [{
                "departure": "departure1",
                "destination": "destination1",
                "time": {
                    departure: 10,
                    destination: 12
                },
                "price": 2000
            }, {
                "departure": "departure2",
                    "destination": "destination2",
                    "time": {
                        departure: 12,
                        destination: 14
                    },
                    "price": 4000
            }, {
                "departure": "departure3",
                    "destination": "destination3",
                    "time": {
                        departure: 14,
                        destination: 16
                    },
                    "price": 8000
            }]
        };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in response.flights">
      <dir>{{item.departure}}</dir>
      <dir>{{item.destination}}</dir>
      <dir>{{iteme.time.departure}}</dir>
      <dir>{{item.time.destination}}</dir>
      <dir>{{item.price}}</dir>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

check the docu: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thank you very much for this approach, I know how to do it with angularjs but I want to use expressjs. All my datas are in my expressjs file, and then I send it to my angularjs file. I updated my code with my angularjs code to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

you do need to use a `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="flight in response.flights">
    <dir>{{flight.departure}}</dir>
    <dir>{{flight.destination}}</dir>
    <dir>{{flight.time.departure}}</dir>
    <dir>{{flight.time.destination}}</dir>
    <dir>{{flight.price}}</dir>
</div>
```

[Reference for ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

A good reference for anything Angular can be found on the [documentation site for AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)

Comment: thank you @Malachi, but when I write my res.json() function like that : res.json(response); it doesn't display anything. How do I write it then in my express post form function ?

Comment: no I don't have, but I can tell you. When I submit, I can see there is no error, but nothing is displayed. I can see it tries to display datas but it put blank space instead. Does it help?

Comment: its ok, it works, I just add flight in response.FLIGHTS

Comment: I am still not used to getting the objects out of JSON.  glad you got it to work, @maevy